# To what degree does this Design violate Encapsulation

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, object-oriented-analysis

I am designing a graph object in Java. Me being the designer I doubt that this design violates encapsulation but I would like some insight from others.

Down below, we have the two interfaces Graph and Vertex.

Graph implementations are responsible for managing vertices in the graph, which consists of there creation, removal, ensuring imposed constraints, etc. The generic parameters stand for **T**ype, the type of the values stored in a vertex, and **W**eight which is the type of the weights stored in edges:

```
public interface Graph<T, W>
{
    /** Creates and adds a vertex with the value given to this graph */
    Vertex<T> createVertex(T value);

    /** Performs some arbitrary modification to the vertex given */
    void modify(Vertex<T> vertex, ....);

    // some other methods...
}
```

The Vertex interface is used for getting and modifying properties of a vertex and also to keep a reference; its implementation is determined by the implementation of the graph - the client does not know anything about its internal implementation. It could look like this:

```
public interface Vertex<T>
{
     int getValue();

     /** Performs some arbitrary modification to this vertex - same as
       * as in modify method in graph */
     void modify(...);

     // some other methods
}
```

The reason I use a vertex interface is so that the client can simply keep a reference to the vertex in question and pass the reference to the graph. I could also have a graph interface like this:

```
public interface Graph<T, W>
{
    /** Creates and adds a vertex with the value given to this graph */
    void createVertex(T value);

    /** Performs some arbitrary modification to the vertex given */
    void modify(T vertex);

    // some other methods...
}
```

In this graph interface the 'modify' method would always have to search for the vertex; this would be very impractical especially when we want to modify the same vertex often - instead the client can just keep a reference pass that like in the first approach.

To come to my question, I am very strict with encapsulation, does this violate the principles of encapsulation?

Personally, I do not think it would violate encapsulation because the client does not know what is performed internally by the the graph object nor by the vertex. However, we do leak the information that the graph uses vertices somehow (though the **exact** internal structure is not exposed) which is not done is other libraries. Examples might be data structures which are subsets of Graphs, such as Trees and LinkedLists: the LinkedList implementation in the core Java libraries does not let the application notice that some Node interface is utilised; tree implementations which I have seen in various other libraries do not expose their Nodes either.

So under strict object oriented terms, does this design violate encapsulation, or does it not? Additional references to existing object-oriented libraries, also outside the spectrum of Java, or articles discussing this topic, I would also welcome.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it does break encapsulation. There's such a thing as over-design and rendering your structure useless or cumbersome. Comparing the graph to a list isn't exactly 1 : 1 either. The list hides those aspects because they're useless or dangerous to expose - the user *shouldn't* care about how things get listed as long as they are as expected. Giving someone a reference to a node is just bad; there'd be no way to guarantee the validity of the list.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I like your point about usefulness but the statement alone is not convincing enough for me, although it is very already. My LinkedList example is not a very good one, I agree. I should give a better one: consider some extendable tree with the least constraints imaginable. It would be rather impractical to have to look for the same node all the time to modify it; I could argue that it makes the client depend on the usage of the node object for operating on the graph; in my opinion, encapsulation is also protecting the client from too much knowledge about the data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to Map interface exposing Map.Entry. The concept of graph presupposes the concept of vertex - you can't have one without the other. It is thus completely legitimate to expose both.

On the other hand, you're exposing (or may be limiting) at least some implementation details here. Your

```
void modify(T vertex);
```

in `Graph` assumes that vetexes are addressable by their contents. That may not always be the case. I think this is too much of a restriction on T.

I'd say that, to ensure encapsulation, the only interrogation operation on the graph itself should be `Set<Vertex<T>> getVertices`. The rest should be on the vertex.

Creation operation should return the entity it creates:

```
Vertex<T> createVertex(T value)
```

You can then add `Graph.createEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2)` and `removeEdge(Vertex<T> v1, Vertex<T> v2)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bit with the implementation detail. I have  method like your getVertices, in fact, though I believe the return type should be a set, not a list, (because I think vertex instances should not be duplicate, though vertices with duplicate values of T may be). A method such as Set<Vertex<T>> search(T type) would not presuppose such implementation details, as I believe.

Comment: RIght you are - set is a better fit. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it does not violate encapsulation. The purpose of a graph is typically to manage vertices and edges so it makes perfect sense to expose and use those concepts as types. In your question you cite `LinkedList`, but the primary purpose of that is to be a `List` and not a node-exposing data structure. It could perfectly safely expose its nodes if it would like, though most clients should just use its `List` API.

Breaking encapsulation is that line where you have exposed the internals in an unsafe manner, such as returning a mutable collection (e.g. `List<Vertex<T>>`) which is an internal data structure instead of protecting it through more controlled API (e.g. `add(Vertex<T>)`, etc.). If you've lost control of your innards, the whole world can play with your privates and there is little you can do about it.

Some `Map` interfaces for example expose a collection representing keys or values, and tie those implementations to be backed by the map itself for mutations. This is safe yet convenient exposure.

Consider not exposing things like internal data structures, boolean or bitwise flags (perhaps use enums or interfaces in the API and something more efficient as needed internally), or mutators that have tricky order of operations such as "first call `init`, then call `setup`, then call `x` or `y` or `z` then make sure to `dispose`". That kind of thing you want to bake into your API with convenience structures and common design patterns.

Comment: Yes, they could expose the `Node`s if they like and write the most dangerous list in existence.

Comment: Of course they could. Encapsulation is all about protected exposure, not impenetrable black boxes: that is what supertypes are for. If you don't want to expose implementation details, provide a higher type in the hierarchy. It is perfectly licit to have a linked list expose nodes for complex operations as long as it guards invariants and callers know what to expect and use it properly.

Comment: The difference, at least how I'm reading it, is who the callers are. Sure, exposing nodes is required at an appropriate level to achieve the responsibilities of the list. But the *end user* of a `List<T>` is expecting to `get()` a `T` not a `Node` while the user of a graph is actually expecting an `Edge` or `Vertex` depending on the imp. Expecting "callers [to] know what to expect and use it properly"  is a big gamble. In summary I'd say, at the level OP is talking about, the end user is what they're worried about.  Could be wrong about that though.

Comment: The level we are talking about is the level of the client which is some user of the Graph interfaces. Though this should not matter because any caller that is not a Graph or Vertex object is the outside world from which we must protect access. My question focuses on the point that we are exposing the vertex interface.

Comment: @univise, that is true. And this is what I dislike about the list example. Paul is saying it's appropriate to expose the nodes of a list for a given situation. I'm saying, yes, but the user is different. Client is a very vague term used for any person using your structure. However, those clients are not always created equally. Further, a graph operates on E or V types by its nature; not the case with a list. So "exposing" a vertex, IMHO, is somewhat implied. Plenty of good algo books who add Vs or Es with `add(Edge e)` which backs my view of it not breaking it. Plenty of examples out there...